# Minimum distance between two skewed lines

Tags: vectors

My doubt is related to minimum distance between skewed lines.

Vector AB where b and a are position vectors of AB and  points on L1 and L2 respectively.

The perpendicular distance PQ is the projection of AB on the normal

How does projecting the vector AB on the normal give us the perpendicular distance.

And what is the guarantee that the projection is not greater than the perpendicular distance.

Comment: Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on it???

Comment: The hypoteneuse length of a right triangle is always greater than the length of the legs.

Comment: I know you people  are trying your best but I still don't get it....

Comment: How does the pythogarean theorem come into play over here???